# How do I get Onchain, the timestamp in milliseconds at which a specific slot was finalized

Tags: solana-program, slots

I am working on a piece of code, but require to know the timestamp in best case milliseconds, and worst case seconds, at which a specific slot number was executed.

is there historical data onchain that I can tap into?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  The highest resolution on-chain wall timestamp available today is one second and available in the `unix_timestamp` field of the [`Clock` sysvar](https://docs.rs/solana-program/latest/solana_program/clock/struct.Clock.html).

Sampling theory states, via [Nyquist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_rate), that there is nothing to be gained by sampling higher than twice a signal's period.  Given that the (target) slot rate of the cluster is 400ms and that slots are essentially samples, attempting to resolve below 800ms fraught at best

Comment: so presuming, the best resolution I can get is seconds, then what about the historical pieces?

can I in a trustless solana program, know at what specific second, a slot was finalized?